# cannot execute binary files on MAC terminal

Tags: c, macos, shell, gcc

I've used makefile to generate file.
**gcc -c hello.c -o hello**
and fixed the permission problem through:
**chmod a+x ./hello**
However, when I want to execute "hello" file.
**./hello**
the system told me that "cannot execute binary file"
Can someone help me? I am looking forward your reply badly.

Comment: Can you post the content of `file ./hello` please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The -c argument to gcc produces an object file which you later on must link in order to produce an executable. You can not execute the object file you produced.

Instead, to compile and link at the same time, suitable when you only have 1 .c file, do

```
gcc hello.c -o hello
```

Or if you want to break it down to separate compilation and linking steps, do

```
gcc -c hello.c -o hello.o
gcc hello.o -o hello
```

Answer (score 2):

Check whether the GCC compiler is installed in your system correctly or not.

```
gcc -v
```

Compile your file:

```
gcc filename.cpp -o any-name
```

Running your program:

```
./any-name
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to compiling and linking at the same time you can use `make`:

```
make hello
```

*Note: without the `.c` extension.*

The terminal output should be:

```
cc     hello.c   -o hello
```